# PHP - get Time independent of the system it is running on

Tags: php, datetime, time

I'm using PHP and need to do some time based actions. I have 2 servers set up on two different machines. However both system clocks are different. I ended up setting both clocks to same time, a trivial task but Is there a PHP method which returns the time independent of the system clock?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where would you expect PHP to get the time independent of the system clock?

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering if it fetches it from dedicated time servers.

Comment: It doesn't, but you could make it. Check out the cURL library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as PHP (and OS) is concerned, system time *is* the time. There is no other "independent" time the computer knows about. If you really do not trust the clock of your own system, you might want to fetch it across the network from some other machine. NTP synchronization daemon will do it for you on OS level, by the way.

Comment: Thank you very much. I guessed as much.